# How can I repair damaged drywall?

Tags: repair, drywall, patching-drywall

I live in a rental house. My pit bull terrier ate the drywall and now I have a home inspection coming up.

What can I do?

Comment: To add a picture, just edit your post and hit control-G. It does the same thing as clicking on the little picture icon in the message editor.

Comment: Standard drywall patch job. And get that dog some training.

Comment: [How to post an image](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/524/33)

Comment: Do a web search on "How to Patch Holes in Drywall".

Answer (score 1):

Just buy a little tub of joint compound, or spackling and cover up the areas.  You will have to paint it as well.  If it is a hole then get a small piece of drywall slightly bigger than the hole but where you can still get it inside (you may have to cut it bigger).  Drill a hole in the middle to fit a piece of string in it.  This will help you to hold it to the wall.  Use joint compound on the edges like glue.  When it dries, fill the void with more joint compound.  I've repaired many fist-size holes from when I was a teenager.

Answer (score 1):

1. Cut out the damaged area with a drywall saw or utility knife in a uniform square or rectangle.

- Find the nearest stud to the left of the damage
- cut from the center of that stud to the center of nearest stud on the right of the damage ( this will give you a place to screw the new drywall into)

3. Take a large piece of the removed drywall to a paint store (lowes or home depot can do it too) and ask them to match the paint and purchase a small can.
4. Buy a section of sheetrock at least the size of what you removed, also purchase some spackling and some drywall screws, and a sanding block, you'll also need a putty knife if not a mudding tool.
5. cut the section of sheetrock to fit
6. screw fitted drywall on to hole in wall with drywall screws going into the studs you exposed in step 1.
7. use spackling and putty knife to carefully fill in and smooth out your seams. Wait to dry
8. sand over the new spackling to smooth out
9. clean thee dust from sanding from the surface and paint over the repaired wall with your paint.